# QI but not ME : not finitely presented groups!

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ergodic-theory, geometric-group-theory

I would like to know the examples of two groups which are not finitely presented and are quasi-isometric (QI), but they are not measured equivalent (ME) (in the sense of Gromov). 
In the literature, there are two types of examples of discrete countable groups which are QI but not ME. These are of following types ( http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/gaboriau/Travaux-Publi/Cambridge/Gaboriau-Cambridge.pdf, page 173) :

1. The groups $\{F_p*(F_2\times F_2) : p\in \mathbb{N}\}$ are mutually bi-Lipschitz. If we compute the $l^2$-betti numbers of the group $F_p*(F_2\times F_2)$, they are (0, p,1,0,0,...) . By a result of D. Gaboriau, if two groups are ME, the $l^2$-betti numbers of the groups are proportional. If we use this result, we obtain that  $F_p*(F_2\times F_2)$ and $F_{p'}*(F_2\times F_2)$ are QI but not ME for $p\neq p'$.
2. We take a cocompact  lattice $\Gamma$ in $Sp(n,1)$ $(n\geq 2)$ and we consider the following two central extensions: one is the inverse image of 
   $\Gamma$ in the universal cover of $Sp(n,1)$, denoted by $\tilde{\Gamma}$, and another one is $\Gamma\times\mathbb{Z}$ . Since $\tilde{\Gamma}$ has Property (T) and  $\Gamma\times\mathbb{Z}$ does not have Property (T), using the invariance of Property (T) under ME by A. Furman , we obtain that these two groups are QI but not ME.

But these two classes of groups are finitely presented. If we look for the examples of infinitely presented groups, we can immediately discard lamp-lighter groups, because they are amenable, and by a result of Y. Shalom,  QI implies ME for amenable groups.

There might be some constructions using the examples of infinitely presented groups with Property (T) (and using the trick of second example as stated above). The examples are as follows:   $SL_3( \mathbb{F}_p[t])$, where $\mathbb{F}_p[t]$ is the ring polynomials over the field with p elements, or $Sp_4(Z[1/p])\ltimes (Z[1/p])^4 $ (this one is due to Y. de Cornulier  ) 
 (see book by Bekka-de la Harpe-Valette https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf , page 184) .

Comment: Take two examples $G_1,G_2$ (QI not ME) and take the direct product $G_1\times H$ and $G_2\times H$ with a single infinitely presented group $H$. The resulting groups are QI. With suitable choices they're not ME (e.g., choose $H,G_1$ with property T but not $G_2$)

Comment: PS you refer to Shalom (2004), but by Ornstein-Weiss (1980) all infinite countable amenable groups are measure equivalent (Shalom implies something stronger).

Comment: @ Yves: Yes, it works! Thank you very much!   Yes, you are right, Ornstein-Weiss will be sufficient. I was thinking about some general phenomenon which is not required here.

Comment: As regards the two examples you mention, I'd tend to believe that every group QI to them also has Property T. However I'm not sure it's known. It would be interesting to single out QI-closed subclasses of the class of groups with property encompassing large classes such as lattices in semisimple groups (over products of nondiscrete locally compact fields) with finite center and factors of rank $\ge 2$.

Comment: These questions sound interesting, thanks! Will it be possible to get examples (of the original question ) where the groups are , moreover,  simple? Although, in the existing examples  ( both in 1 & 2 ), the groups are not simple !

Comment: Probably it's unknown whether there exist f.g. groups that are QI and not ME, one of which being simple.